# error: incompatible types int[] cannot be converted to int[][]

Tags: java

I do not understand why I cannot compile my code. I get two errors which mean about the same thing. However, when i do the same thing within other methods no errors, yet. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I have only been working with java for about a year so I have a lot to learn.

Errors:

```
method doThings in class Main cannot be applied to given types;
doThings(obj.getStuff());
^

incompatible types int[] cannot be converted to int[][]
int[][] s = o.getStuff();
                      ^
```

Edit: The original code snippet I posted did not actually have the error so here is the full code

Main: pastebin.com/Rp85vCUT 
More Class: pastebin.com/EzPyUvn2

Comment: There are couple of issues I am seeing with the code provided... 1. You can't call a non static method (doThing) from a static main method? 2. You are instantiating Object, not object. Is that a typo(though discouraged to give your class such a reserved name). Please post your actual code.

Comment: Although type names are case-sensitive, and `object` is a *legal* name for a class, you should name your class something else. Something that starts with a capital letter.

Comment: I know this is just an example I made, it has a few typos but it gives an easier to read example than 2 100+ line code files.

Comment: add the semicolon and compile your example with the modification and it is going to compile, maybe you have another problem but your code doesn't replicate that.

Comment: Alright here is the full code:
Main: http://pastebin.com/Rp85vCUT
More Class: http://pastebin.com/EzPyUvn2

Answer (score 0):

In Main class you have `object obj = new Object();`. It should be `object obj = new object();`

Also youre missing a semicolon in main method `doThings(obj.getStuff());`

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code for the next:

```
class object {
    private int[][] s;

    public object() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public object(int[][] s) {
        super();
        this.s = s;
    }

    public int[][] getStuff() {
        return s;
    }

    public void doSomething(int[][] stuff) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        object obj = new object();
        doThings(obj.getStuff());
    }

    public static int[][] doThings(int[][] s) {
        // doing things
        return s;
    }

    public void doMoreThings(object o) {
        int[][] s = o.getStuff();
    }

    public object doOtherThings(object o) { // no errors, yet
        o.doSomething(o.getStuff());
        return new object(o.getStuff());
    }
}
```

The problems are the next:

1. You need two constructors  because you are creating the object in 2 ways.
2. Replace new Object() by new object() because Object is another class that already exists.
3. Make the `doThings` method static.
4. Add the missing `doSomething` method in the object class.
5. You are missing a semicolon in main method `doThings(obj.getStuff());`

Comment: Thanks, but those are just little errors/typos I forgot about when I wrote this question. I double checked my main program does not have those errors. I still get the two errors shown in my original question even with your corrections.

Comment: copy complete the code and It is going to compile, you didn't fixt a semicolon in the  doThings(obj.getStuff())